# Extract data from textfile in python

Tags: python

I need to write a python function that reads and stores values from a textfile that looks as follows:

[image]

I need to store the variables ncols, nrows….. until NODATA_value, and stop there. So only the first 6 lines are needed. Any tips?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please begin with a basic Python tutorial.

Comment: I use np.loadtxt to store the matrix occuring after those 6 lines. I know how to read line by line but i want the function to skip those spaces btw the varible name and the value

Comment: Can you actually post the text of the file in a code block instead of a screenshot? Are those tabs or spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```py
variables = dict()
with open('my_text_file.txt', 'r') as textfile:
    while True:    
        next_line = textfile.readline()
        if len(next_line) == 0:
            break

        key, value = next_line.split()
        if key == 'NODATA_value':
            break

        variables[key] = value
```

This assumes that each line in your file is a key-value pair, where the key and value are separated by some amount of whitespace.

The loop will terminate when the end of the file is reached, or when the `NODATA_value` key is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this is very simple to do. I recommend you to see a python tutorial. Anyway this can be a start point.:

```
width open("myfile.txt") as f:
  for idx,line in enumerate(f):
    if idx>=6: break
    #dostuff
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many nice libraries that will do this for you, but it's basic Python to do this without learning new libraries. You can put the contents of the folder into a list: [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

From there, it's easy. Use list.index(element) to find the index of 'ncols', and the index of its value is list.index('ncols')+1. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index

You could use slicing to crop the list off at NODATA_value: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)